# AT&T Assembly carry flag

Tags: assembly, flags, att, carryflag

I need some help in AT&T assembly again, I've load some data into memory like below (hex and dec).

```
(gdb) x/8xb &buffer_in
0x8049096:  0x03    0x02    0x10    0x27    0xe8    0x03    0x64    0x00


(gdb) x/8db &buffer_in
0x8049096:   3        2      16      39      -24      3      100      0
```

Lets say that first byte = number count, second = each number length in bytes and then we got (first * second) bytes of numbers. For this example, 3 numbers, 2 bytes each, first number is 16 39 and so one. I would like to add each number, so in this case it would be adding 0x10 + 0xe8 (lower byte) to result[0] then 0x27 + 0x03 to result[1] and then again, result[0] = result[0] + 0x64 and finally result[1] = result[1] + 0x00.

When I'm adding 0x64 to result[0] which already contains 0xf8, the CF (carry flag) is set, and that's great of course because I would like to use this carry in result[1] next addition. **But the problem is** that after next CMP instruction (I'll mark it on code below) this carry flag is cleared so the final result is 0x5C2A (when I combine two bytes of result) and should be 0x5C2B (but the carry flag didnt affect the addition due to cmp instruction).

%eax - amount of numbers to sum

%ecx - length of each number in bytes

%esi - before loops start is pointing to first byte of 'real' data (0x10 in this case)

```
loop1:

movl $0, %ebx

    loop2:
    leal (%esi, %ebx, 1), %edi
    movb (%edi), %dl  # %dl contain now next byte to add
    adc %dl, result(%ebx) # adding to result

    inc %ebx
    cmp %ebx, %ecx # this comparsion clears CF flag and that's the problem
    JG loop2

leal (%esi, %ecx, 1), %esi

dec %al
cmp $0, %al
JG loop1
```

Comment: Would pushf/popf work for you? For example, do pushf before loop2 label, popf right after it and then again pushf before cmp instruction. This should save/restore status (flags) register thus preserving the carry flag across cmp..

Comment: @Sokre it's working, also have just trying pushf popf but ur correct sollution came first! thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

This is usually resolved by adjusting logic of algorithm to avoid any CF-changing instruction between `add` and `adc`, which may look actually a bit impossible at first sight, when you want loop over dynamic count of bytes.

But if you will read details about instructions [`INC`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_140.html) and [`DEC`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_71.html), there's one interesting thing, which looks like weird inconsistency. They don't affect CF! (it was actually designed like that just because of similar use cases, like this one).

So your code may look like this (sorry for Intel+NASM syntax, I don't like AT&T, so convert on your own, at least you will know for sure you understand it well) (plus I didn't debug it, so it may have some bug, let me know in case there's a problem):

```
    ; zero the result data first
    movzx    edx,byte [buffer_in+1]  ; element length
zero_result:
    dec      edx
    mov      [result+edx],byte 0
    jnz      zero_result
    ; now sum all elements
    movzx    ecx,byte [buffer_in+0]  ; number of elements
    lea      esi,[buffer_in+2]       ; source data ptr
elements_loop:
    movzx    edx,byte [buffer_in+1]  ; element length
    xor      ebx,ebx       ; offset of byte of element = 0 AND CF=0 (!)
element_byte_loop:
    mov      al,[esi]      ; read source byte (no CF change)
    inc      esi           ; ++ptr (CF preserved)
    adc      [result+ebx],al   ; add it to result with CF
    inc      ebx           ; next offset of byte inside element (CF preserved)
    dec      edx           ; do all bytes of element (CF preserved)
    jnz      element_byte_loop
    ; single element added to result, now repeat it for all elements
    dec      ecx
    jnz      elements_loop
```

Comment: plus1 for only using Intel syntax.

Comment: [ADOX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29747508/995714) was added for improving big int math performance and can also be used to avoid changing of CF

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, true, but that limits your code to a very select group of very new processors. And there are better ways of solving the problem. You can make the loop smaller and faster, see my answer below (esp the last part).

Comment: Sure.. btw, this is by no means "production" quality code, it's done in simple way for educational reasons. If I would have to do something similar in real world, I would probably dynamically compile unrolled loop with SIMD instructions, and keep using that (especially if size of element would be fixed for many data sets).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the carry flag there are a few tricks for that.

**push the flags**

```
pushf   //save the flags
...... do stuff
popf    //restore the flags
```

**save CF in a register**

```
//save CF in eax
sbb eax,eax     //CF=1 -> CF=1, regx=-1; CF=0 -> CF=0, regx=0, clobbers other flags
//note that sbb reg, reg preserves! CF, how cool is that!
.... do stuff, do not alter eax
add eax,1         //restore CF
```

**rewrite the loop so it counts <del>down</del> up to zero**

```
loop1:
  mov ebx,ecx        //ebx = count
  lea esi,[esi+ecx]  //esi = end of buffer
  neg ebx            //ebx = -count
loop2:
  //no need for the lea (the mov can do complex addressing)
  mov dl,[esi+ebx]  # %dl contain now next byte to add
  adc [ecx+ebx+result],dl adding to result
  inc ebx            //ebx will be zero when done :-)
//no need for cmp
  jnz loop2           //we only need ZF
```

Just in case you missed it. The trick works as follows.
First we add count to the base pointer.
Next we negate the count.
The loop thus starts at `basepointer+count-count = basepointer`
At every iteration we increase `-count`.
This leads to the following effect in loop iteration `n`: `address = base+count-count+n` ergo: `adr = base + n`.
When we are done `-count+n` will be zero, and we don't need to do a `cmp` because the `inc` will adjust `ZF` for as as needed without clobbering `CF`.

Note that I only use Intel syntax as a matter of principle.

Comment: lahf and sahf perform better than pushf and popf.